# How to sort Table with data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm working on a tool where user can type in a username and then I display the data I fetch from GitHub about that specific user. Even though each cell responds to sorting they only sort the data according to the first cell. If I click the first cell which is Repository Name I get expected result but when I do click to other cells they still getting sorted according to the Repository Name cell. I'm getting stuck somewhere and can not really see it. I would appreciate if you could help me with showing me the way to sort each cell independently.

Here is the code I have:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import _ from 'lodash'
import Moment from 'react-moment';

const UserTable = (props) => {
    const [column, setColumn] = useState(null);
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [direction, setDirection] = useState(null);

    const handleSort = (clickedColumn) => () => {

        if (column !== clickedColumn) {

            setColumn(clickedColumn)
            setData(_.sortBy(data, [clickedColumn]))
            setDirection('ascending')
            return
        }
        setData(props.repoData.reverse())
        setDirection(direction === 'ascending' ? 'descending' : 'ascending')
    }



    return (
        <div>
            <Table sortable celled fixed>
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell
                            sorted={column === 'name' ? direction : null}
                            onClick={handleSort('name')}
                        >
                            Repository Name
            </Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell
                            sorted={column === 'description' ? direction : null}
                            onClick={handleSort('description')}
                        >
                            Description
            </Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell
                            sorted={column === 'since' ? direction : null}
                            onClick={handleSort('since')}
                        >
                            Created At
            </Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>
                <Table.Body>
                    {props.repoData.map(repos => {
                        return <Table.Row>

                            <Table.Cell>{repos.name}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{repos.description}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell> <Moment format="DD-MM-YYYY">{repos.created_at}</Moment></Table.Cell>
                        </Table.Row>
                    })}


                </Table.Body>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default UserTable;
```

**PS:** `props.repoData` is the data I get from GitHub about that specific user.

Answer (score 0):

seems the issue with multiple updates, Since `setSate` is async, so combine, state update together.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Table } from "semantic-ui-react";
import _ from "lodash";
import Moment from "react-moment";

const UserTable = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    column: null,
    data: null,
    direction: null,
  });
  const { column, data, direction } = state;
  const handleSort = (clickedColumn) => () => {
    if (column !== clickedColumn) {
      setState({
        data: _.sortBy(data, [clickedColumn]),
        column: clickedColumn,
        direction: "ascending",
      });
      return;
    }
    setState({
      data: props.repoData.reverse(),
      column: clickedColumn,
      direction: direction === "ascending" ? "descending" : "ascending",
    });
  };
};

export default UserTable;
```

Comment: what is `setDirection()` in this case? I get an error as its not defined.

Comment: typo. removed it

Comment: Still reverses only according to name column. The others doesn't behave on its own.

Comment: u are free to modify the code according to logic. i am trying to highlight.. do atomic update.. it will fix your issue.

Comment: That's where I am having struggles. I didn't had problem in anywehere else in this code but sorting. I'm having trouble to understand how does the code provided helps me in my problem.